# Update a date in SQL using DATEADD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update several datetime records in a sql table.
The values which i'm trying to update are all like this: 2019-01-01 23:59:59.000 and I'm looking to update them adding one second to each record with this 23:59:59 time in order to make them shift to the next day with 00:00:000 time.

The query I am executing now it gives the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

Here's the query that fails:

```
update electriccons
set dateEvent = (select DATEADD(second, +1, dateEvent) from electriccons)
where (DATEPART(hour, dateEvent) = 23 and DATEPART(minute, dateEvent) = 59)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why not just omit the `(select` and `from electriccons)`? If you want to update the current record from itself, you don't need to / should not specify any other data source.

Comment: Because the subquery returned more than 1 value. You should use for loop or cursor in this situation.

Comment: what is this? where is this code? is this meant to be run when you save some data ?

Comment: thanks @underscore_d your first comment helped me. I shouldn't have specified the "from" for the second time. Omitting that (`select` and `from electriccons`) it works just fine... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this Microsoft SQL Server? Your syntax should be something more like:

```
Update electriccons
Set dateEvent = DATEADD(second, +1, dateEvent)
Where DATEPART(hour, dateEvent) = 23 and DATEPART(minute, dateEvent) = 59
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @underscore_d said, is there a reason the following won't work?

```
update electriccons
set dateEvent = DATEADD(second, +1, dateEvent)
where (DATEPART(hour, dateEvent) = 23 and DATEPART(minute, dateEvent) = 59)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
update electriccons
    set dateEvent = dateadd(second, +1, dateEvent)
    where convert(time, dateEvent) = '23:59:59';
```

For the filtering condition, you might really want:

```
    where convert(time, dateEvent) >= '23:59:59';
```

There are two issues with your query.  First, a subquery is not needed for the `set`.  Second, you are not limiting the `update` to exactly the rows that you specify.

You could also express the filtering logic as:

```
where convert(date, dateEvent) <> convert(date, dateadd(second, 1, dateEvent))
```

I think this logic is probably what you really want.